# urlencode() does not encode harm full charcters like <

Tags: php, url

We know `<`  and`>`   are not url safe characters , but `urlencode()` does not encode them into url safe characters ,

so what can i do to converts these all url unsafe characters into url safe characters

### UPDATE

`urlencode()` encodes the `<` and `>`, But when i click  on the link  it still shows me the same url unsafe character appearing in the browser url

For example in source code if i i have

```
<a href='%3C'> < is encoded as %3C </a>
```

But when this link is parsed by browser and you hover over this link , u will see link is `<` And  even when u click on this link , this unsafe character `<` will appear  in browser url

So what does the point of encode `<` as `%3C`

I think i am really misunderstanding the concept , can someone help me to clear my concept ?

Comment: It should and it does to `%3C` and `%3E` https://eval.in/708089

Comment: What version of php are you using? Also, can you provide the code your using to get that result

Comment: My code is all messed up ,  i don't know what i am doing wrong , but `urlencode()` works fine , something wrong in my code , i have to find the problem myself,  thanks @Thamilan .

Comment: @Thamilan I updated the question , would u please help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is decoding the characters **for display** to make it easier to read the data in the URL. It will still send the encoded versions to the HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks, But then why it show space as + or %20 , why it don't decode + as space

Comment: @beginner — Because it isn't a very good feature (it tries to avoid decoding characters which might be ambiguous, which is just confusing in a different way).

Comment: i am still confused , But that is my problem, .

Comment: Quentin is correct -- if you inspect the actual request you'll see that the browser _sent_ it in the manner you expect, it's just _presenting_ it differently. Whilst the usefulness of this feature is debatable, it does exist and this isn't the only thing browsers manipulate -- it's always best to look at the actual request to see what's really happening.